# Laravel Nova custom tool - redirect to login page if not authenticated

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-nova, laravel-middleware

**Problem**

After creating several Laravel Nova tools, I discovered that it was possible to navigate to a custom tool, even though the user logged out in a different tab.

[image: Laravel Nova tool still accessible even while unauthenticated.]

**Explanation**

In the [Laravel Nova docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html#routing-authorization), it is stated that the out-of-the-box Authorization Middleware of Laravel Nova takes care of the authentication of routes that are specified within your Tool's routes group. Which seems to work; when I log out in a different tab and try to navigate to my custom tool, it does show the view, but it does not load any HTTP (Axios) calls that I tried to make. It returns the following message:

```
{message: "Unauthenticated."}
```

Which makes sense, because the Authorization middleware returns a aborts the request with `403 status code`. Laravel Nova takes care of this using the `AuthenticationException` file:

```
/**
 * Render the exception.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => $this->getMessage()], 401);
    } elseif ($request->is('nova-api/*') || $request->is('nova-vendor/*')) {
        return redirect()->to($this->location());
    }

    return redirect()->guest($this->location());
}
```

Any calls made to the `nova-api/*` routes or `nova-vendor/*` routes are caught and redirected to the login page. So trying to access the "regular" Laravel Nova resource when unauthenticated results in being redirect to the login page of Laravel Nova.

Unfortunately, the route for displaying the view of the tool itself is done in a separate `tool.js` file, where the route is directly bound to the component, as shown below:

```
Nova.booting((Vue, router, store) => {
  router.addRoutes([
    {
      name: 'mailable-previewer',
      path: '/mailable-previewer',
      component: require('./components/Tool'),
    },
  ])
})
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried overriding the exception message to return a redirect, but unfortunately, this does not work, the view is still visible and the Laravel Nova login page is only visible in the response in the network tab, as it does not redirect the user directly.

A workaround I found was to do an axios call in the custom `Tool.vue` file, where a `401 status code` should reload the page (and thus activating the Authorization middleware of Laravel Nova again which redirect the user to the login page).

**What I would like to achieve**

Find a way to redirect a unauthenticated user to the Laravel Nova login page ***before*** the custom Tool component is loaded. Is this maybe possible using:

1. Extending the `tool.js` file with some kind of middleware to somehow prevent navigating to the tab when the user is unauthenticated?

Any direction to a right answer is much appreciated!